# Python: What am I doing wrong

Tags: python

I am learning how to code. This is my code:

```
race = 'Daytona 500' 
print( race , 'is' + type( race )  )
```

And the error is:

```
print( race , 'is' + type( race ) )
TypeError: must be str, not type
```

Please help, what am I doing wrong

Comment: Is there something that the pretty clear error message confuses you here? Did you anything to fix this?

Comment: Yes, I am actually just a beginner and studying the book "Coding for beginners. I am getting this same error for two days

Comment: Well a `type` isn't a `str` so what do you think you need to do, I'm not trying to offend you here but you need to demonstrate effort rather than posting a question stating you get an error. Here the error is very clear

Comment: In the book it says to write that in, and I am just typing whatever it says in the book. I tried replacing type with 'Daytona 500' or 'Daytona' but the error says 'str' object is not callable.

Comment: well what you are trying to do is to concatenate two objects of type "str" and type "type" which is not allowed, if you are trying to print the type of race you can do print( race , 'is' , type( race ) )

Comment: Thank you, that also works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use `format` here

```
race = 'Daytona 500' 
print( race + ' is '+'{}'.format(type(race)))
```

It will print `Daytona 500 is <type 'str'>`

Comment: Thank, you're a genius!

Comment: I don't know how your method works and the method the book gives is wrong, so strange.

Comment: it would be easy to do print( race ,'is',type(race))
you dont even need the space around is

Comment: @WalidMashal But it also prints the brackets and commas like `('Daytona 500', 'is', <type 'str'>)`

Comment: Walid Marshall, oh ok that also works, I thought I have to do everything that the book says.

Comment: @ChandaKorat did you check it in python 2.7, because in python 2.7 it prints the brackets(means it prints it as a tuple) but in python 3.5.2 it does not.

Comment: @WalidMashal yeah possible. i have checked with 2.7.9

Comment: for 2.7 you can remove the brackets as print race ,'is',type(race)

Answer (score 2):

you can use as well:

```
print( race + ' is '+ str(type(race)))
```